# Reduce boilerplate around a hand-wrapped `Num` type

Tags: haskell

(With possibly using GHC extensions), is there a way to reduce boilerplate in this kind of code?

```hs
data Operation = Add | Sub | Mult | Div

data Number
    = IntVal Integer
    | FloatVal Double

evaluate :: Operation -> Number -> Number -> Number
evaluate op lhs rhs = case op of
  Add -> case (lhs, rhs) of
    (IntVal i, IntVal j) -> IntVal $ i + j
    (FloatVal x, FloatVal y) -> FloatVal $ x + y
    _ -> undefined

  Sub -> case (lhs, rhs) of
    (IntVal i, IntVal j) -> IntVal $ i - j
    (FloatVal x, FloatVal y) -> FloatVal $ x - y
    _ -> undefined

  Mult -> case (lhs, rhs) of
    (IntVal i, IntVal j) -> IntVal $ i * j
    (FloatVal x, FloatVal y) -> FloatVal $ x * y
    _ -> undefined
```

Deriving `instance Num Number` would run into the same issue.

Comment: It's not clear that `Number` should be a single type. What operations apply to a `Number` that don't care about whether the underlying value is an `Integer` or a `Double`?

Comment: It should probably be a GADT, something like `Number a`, where `IntVal :: Integer -> Number Integer` and `FloatVal :: Double -> Number Double`. It doesn't help implement operations (although you wouldn't need the `undefined` cases), but having the compiler stop you from mixing types is way better than just blowing up at runtime with no warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to reduce the boilerplate of the similar pattern matches, then the standard strategy works. Make a helper function that does the repeating stuff, and pull out the bits that vary into parameters:

```
data Operation = Add | Sub | Mult | Div
  deriving Show

data Number
  = IntVal Integer
  | FloatVal Double
  deriving Show


liftIntFloatBinOp
  :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> (Double -> Double -> Double)
  -> (Number -> Number -> Number)
liftIntFloatBinOp iOp fOp x y
  = case (x, y) of
      (IntVal x', IntVal y') -> IntVal $ x' `iOp` y'
      (FloatVal x', FloatVal y') -> FloatVal $ x' `fOp` y'
      _ -> undefined


evaluate :: Operation -> (Number -> Number -> Number)
evaluate op
 = case op of
     Add -> liftIntFloatBinOp (+) (+)
     Sub -> liftIntFloatBinOp (-) (-)
     Mult -> liftIntFloatBinOp (*) (*)
     Div -> liftIntFloatBinOp div (/)
```

I added `deriving Show` just so you can see it works in ghci:

```
λ let (|*|) = evaluate Mult in IntVal 3 |*| IntVal 7
IntVal 21
it :: Number

λ let (|*|) = evaluate Mult in FloatVal 3 |*| FloatVal 7
FloatVal 21.0
it :: Number

λ let (|*|) = evaluate Mult in FloatVal 3 |*| IntVal 7
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:74:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at foo.hs:19:12 in main:Number
```

If you want, you can then apply the same strategy again to get rid of the repeated calls to `liftIntFloatBinOp` (although with a less verbose name they would matter less anyway), by implementing something like:

```
toIntFloatOps :: Operation -> (Integer -> Integer -> Integer, Double -> Double -> Double)
toIntFloatOps op
  = case op of
      Add -> ((+), (+))
      Sub -> ((-), (-))
      Mult -> ((*), (*))
      Div -> (div, (/))


evaluate :: Operation -> (Number -> Number -> Number)
evaluate = uncurry liftIntFloatBinOp . toIntFloatOps
```

You may have been hoping for something fancy like using `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}` to write:

```
liftNumOp
  :: (forall t. Num t => t -> t -> t)
  -> (Number -> Number -> Number)
liftNumOp op x y
  = case (x, y) of
      (IntVal x', IntVal y') -> IntVal $ x' `op` y'
      (FloatVal x', FloatVal y') -> FloatVal $ x' `op` y'
      _ -> undefined
```

This *does* work to a degree. You can use this to try:

```
λ liftNumOp (*) (IntVal 3) (IntVal 6)
IntVal 18
```

But it fails when you want division:

```
λ liftNumOp (/) (IntVal 3) (IntVal 6)

<interactive>:16:11: error:
    • Could not deduce (Fractional t) arising from a use of ‘/’
      from the context: Num t
        bound by a type expected by the context:
                   forall t. Num t => t -> t -> t
        at <interactive>:16:11-13
      Possible fix:
        add (Fractional t) to the context of
          a type expected by the context:
            forall t. Num t => t -> t -> t
    • In the first argument of ‘liftNumOp’, namely ‘(/)’
      In the expression: liftNumOp (/) (IntVal 3) (IntVal 6)
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = liftNumOp (/) (IntVal 3) (IntVal 6)

λ liftNumOp (div) (IntVal 3) (IntVal 6)

<interactive>:17:12: error:
    • Could not deduce (Integral t) arising from a use of ‘div’
      from the context: Num t
        bound by a type expected by the context:
                   forall t. Num t => t -> t -> t
        at <interactive>:17:11-15
      Possible fix:
        add (Integral t) to the context of
          a type expected by the context:
            forall t. Num t => t -> t -> t
    • In the first argument of ‘liftNumOp’, namely ‘(div)’
      In the expression: liftNumOp (div) (IntVal 3) (IntVal 6)
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = liftNumOp (div) (IntVal 3) (IntVal 6)
```

It fails for the a very simple reason you would have noticed yourself if you'd actually kept going with your original boilerplatey version: there **is** no single division operator that works on both integers and floating point numbers. So there's no polymorphic function you can pass that can be applied to either type your `Number` might contain, even when you use `RankNTypes` to pass an argument function that is "still polymorphic".

So honestly, the low-tech helper function approach is probably better.

Answer (score 3):

In this example you can just reorder the structure:

```
evaluate op lhs rhs = case (lhs, rhs) of
    (IntVal i, IntVal j) -> IntVal $ i % j
    (FloatVal x, FloatVal y) -> FloatVal $ x % y
    _ -> undefined
 where (%) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
       (%) = case op of
         Add -> (+)
         Sum -> (-)
         Mult -> (*)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a generic function first:

```
handling :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> (Float -> Float -> Float) -> Number -> Number -> Number
handling f g = go
  where go (IntVal x) (IntVal y) = IntVal (f x y)
        go (FloatVal x) (FloatVal y) = FloatVal (g x y)
        go _ _ = undefined
```

then it is:

```
evaluate :: Operation -> Number -> Number -> Number
evaluate Add = handling (+) (+)
evaluate Sub = handling (-) (-)
evaluate Mult = handling (*) (*)
```

Answer (score 1):

A fairly primitive alternative choice to consider:

```
evaluate op (IntVal l) (IntVal r) = IntVal $ case op of
    Add -> l + r
    Sub -> l - r
    Mult -> l * r

evaluate op (FloatVal l) (FloatVal r) = FloatVal $ case op of
    Add -> l + r
    Sub -> l - r
    Mult -> l * r

evaluate op _ _ = undefined
```

The amount of repetition is not reduced to zero, but it's reduced a lot.